# Mock DBSet<T> and call AsQueryable method return an empty list

Tags: unit-testing, entity-framework-core

I use entity framework core 6, XUnit for testing, Moq 4.16.1

I have a List, Mock it as DBSet<T>, I call AsQueryable method on DBSet<T> then return a empty list. If i mock AsQueryable method on DBSet<T>, i will have a expected list. Can you tell me Why?

This is my code

```
public static class MockDbExtensions
{
    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> MockDbSet<T>(this IQueryable<T> testData) where T : class
    {
        Mock<DbSet<T>> dbSetMock = new Mock<DbSet<T>>();
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Provider).Returns(new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(testData.Provider));
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.Expression).Returns(testData.Expression);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.ElementType).Returns(testData.ElementType);
        dbSetMock.As<IQueryable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetEnumerator()).Returns(() => testData.GetEnumerator());
        dbSetMock.As<IAsyncEnumerable<T>>().Setup(m => m.GetAsyncEnumerator(default)).Returns(() => new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(testData.GetEnumerator()));
        return dbSetMock;
    }

    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> MockDbSet<T>(this IEnumerable<T> elements) where T : class
    {
        var testData = elements.AsQueryable();
        return testData.MockDbSet();
    }

    public static Mock<DbSet<T>> MockDbSet<T>(this T[] elements) where T : class
    {
        var testData = elements.AsQueryable();
        return testData.MockDbSet();
    }
}

internal class TestAsyncQueryProvider<TEntity> : IAsyncQueryProvider
{
    private readonly IQueryProvider _inner;

    internal TestAsyncQueryProvider(IQueryProvider inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TEntity>(expression);
    }

    public IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TElement>(expression);
    }

    public object Execute(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute(expression);
    }

    public TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return _inner.Execute<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerable<TResult> ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerable<TResult>(expression);
    }

    public TResult ExecuteAsync<TResult>(Expression expression, CancellationToken cancellationToken = new CancellationToken())
    {
        var expectedResultType = typeof(TResult).GetGenericArguments()[0];
        var executionResult = ((IQueryProvider)this).Execute(expression);

        return (TResult)typeof(Task).GetMethod(nameof(Task.FromResult))
            .MakeGenericMethod(expectedResultType)
            .Invoke(null, new[] { executionResult });
    }
}

internal class TestAsyncEnumerable<T> : EnumerableQuery<T>, IAsyncEnumerable<T>, IQueryable<T>
{
    public TestAsyncEnumerable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        : base(enumerable)
    { }

    public TestAsyncEnumerable(Expression expression)
        : base(expression)
    { }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    public IAsyncEnumerator<T> GetAsyncEnumerator(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
        return new TestAsyncEnumerator<T>(this.AsEnumerable().GetEnumerator());
    }

    IQueryProvider IQueryable.Provider => new TestAsyncQueryProvider<T>(this);
}

internal class TestAsyncEnumerator<T> : IAsyncEnumerator<T>
{
    private readonly IEnumerator<T> _inner;

    public TestAsyncEnumerator(IEnumerator<T> inner)
    {
        _inner = inner;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
    }

    public T Current => _inner.Current;

    public Task<bool> MoveNext(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.FromResult(_inner.MoveNext());
    }

    public ValueTask<bool> MoveNextAsync() => new ValueTask<bool>(_inner.MoveNext());

    public ValueTask DisposeAsync()
    {
        _inner.Dispose();
        return new ValueTask();
    }
}

public class ReportTemplateServiceTests
{

    private List<ReportTemplateType> CreateReportTemplateTypes()
    {
        return new List<ReportTemplateType>
            {
                new ReportTemplateType { Id = new Guid("144013ED-2D77-4572-8AB4-483C66E4EF1D"), Name = "Financial statements", DisplayOrder = 3, CmsId = 101475, IsActive = true },
                new ReportTemplateType { Id = new Guid("058F8F85-A735-48F3-B526-79855FFF1EB0"), Name = "Reports", DisplayOrder = 1, CmsId = 100473, IsActive = true },
                new ReportTemplateType { Id = new Guid("69D55B31-69BB-4BBC-82F1-A707B484E99B"), Name = "Letters", DisplayOrder = 2, CmsId = 100474, IsActive = true },
                new ReportTemplateType { Id = new Guid("19D2650B-CE8E-4B54-95D9-ACAFA5C1CE40"), Name = "Custom working papers", DisplayOrder = 4, CmsId = 101476, IsActive = true },
            };
    }

    public async void CreateReportTemplateAsync_Success()
    {
        // Arrange
        var reportTemplates = CreateReportTemplates().MockDbSet().Object;


        var a = reportTemplates.AsQueryable().ToList(); // return empty list after call AsQueryable()
    }
}
```

I mock AsQueryable method on DBSet<T>, i will have a expected list.